# Ruby on Rails: Change email user per username in header menu ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, menu, activeadmin, initializer

I am trying to change the user email in the header menu of ActiveAdmin per his username. In the ActiveAdmin documentation there are a method to do this in `config/initializers/active_admin.rb`, but it only allow a static value, and i need to it change per user logins dinamically.

This is the code to make it as static way:

```
config.namespace :admin do |admin|
 admin.build_menu :utility_navigation do |menu|
  menu.add label: 'My label', url: "url/to/whatever"
  admin.add_logout_button_to_menu menu
 end
end
```

I am trying to do some like:

```
config.namespace :admin do |admin|
 admin.build_menu :utility_navigation do |menu|
  menu.add label: current_admin_user.user_name, url: admin_admin_user_path(current_admin_user)
  admin.add_logout_button_to_menu menu
 end
end
```

This is not possible because do not exist sessions when the application is starting (and where ruby interpret the initializer).

Some idea?

All coments are welcome!

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

try to use proc , example

```
 menu.add  :label  => proc{ display_name current_active_admin_user },
                  :url    =>  proc{  edit_admin_admin_user_path(current_active_admin_user) }  ,
                  :id     => 'current_user',
                  :if     => proc{ current_active_admin_user? }
```